How to use item_selector to retrieve data three levels deeper in json object in migrate_plus fro Drupal 10
I am trying to utilise a single json source to import components on to a content type but unable to utilise the item_selector to fetch the field within the json object in drupal 10 using migrate_plus.
Here is the json source
    {
  "fruits": [
    {
      "article_id":1,
      "title": "Test article",
      "body": "fruit seller",
      "citrus": [
        {
          "citrus_id": 1,
          "citrus_title": " Title",
          "citrus_body": " body text here."
        }
      ],
      "tropical": [
        {
          "tropical_id": 1,
          "tropical_title": "Title",
          "tropical_image": "image.jpg",
          "tropical_text": "This is some  text."
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

My item_selector is /fruits/0/citrus but this doesn't work. I also tried /fruits//citrus, 'fruits//citrus' and I dont see any change. what am I missing. I tried following information from migrate_plus examples but no progress.
